# Output latest posts from each child categories of particular parent category

Tags: wordpress, arguments, parent, categories, children

I want to output latest post from each category (child category) that has parent. Parent category id is 54.

For example, if there are 7 child categories under the category 54, the number of output post should be 7 (all latest from each child category). I hope this makes sense.

My current code is below. At this stage, this code outputs only one latest post (of 1 child category) that has the latest under cat id=54. It would be great if you could advise me how to modify this so that I can get more latest post from multiple child categories.

```
<?php 
$categories = get_categories();
foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
    $args = array(
    'cat' => 54,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    );
}
?>
<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
<div class="container">

<?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>   
<div class="box">
<article>
    <p><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) { if (cat_is_ancestor_of(54, $childcat)) { echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">'; echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>'; }} ?></p>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('box-pic'); ?></a><?php endif; ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
</article>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the logic you need to use,

```
$term_id = 54;
$taxonomy_name = 'category';
$term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

echo '<ul>';
foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy_name );

    $args = array(
    'cat' => $term->term_id,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => '1',
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <div class="container">

    <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="box">
    <article>
    <p><?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $childcat) { if (cat_is_ancestor_of(54, $childcat)) { echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">'; echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a>'; }} ?></p>
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ): ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('box-pic'); ?></a><?php endif; ?>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a>
    </h3>
    </article>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile;?>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query();
 }
 echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thank you Ashmed. This works the same as my original code. It just output 1 very latest post from single child category. There are more than 1 (currently 7) categories and those categories have their latest posts. It means that the number of output post should be 7.

Comment: Thread continues here..

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/output-latest-posts-from-each-child-categories-of-particular-parent-category/#post-9072769

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$term_id =54 ;
$term_children = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy );
$term_id = array();

foreach ( $term_children as $child ) {
    $term = get_term_by( 'id', $child, $taxonomy );
    $term_id[] = $term->term_id; //childern ids array.
}
```

Pass the $term_id to tax_query.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => $post_type,
        'posts_per_page' => 7,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $term_id
            )
        ) 
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for this but your code didn't output anything. Also the number of child categories can be changed. Now it is 7 but will be more or less in the future. Therefore I must avoid putting like 7.
Just in case if there is no misunderstanding, "posts_per_page" to be "1" means only one latest post from single child category correct?

Even my original code above can output multiple by changing posts_per_page value.